# Remove "www" from all links to my website - nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I created a Rails app and I would like when I put any link pointing to my website, the "www" to be removed.

For example when someone enters http://www.mydomain.com/users into the browser address, this to be changed into http://mydomain.com/users when the page loads up.

So if I was working with apache I could add this lines to .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However I am working with nginx and unicorn (I am not sure if unicorn has something to do with this).

Do I place something like that in my nginx configuration?

Any resource / point to the right direction will be really helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Ricoxor answered, you **could** use a rewrite to get the correct functionality; however, this is listed as an examplary pitfall in the [Nginx Pitfalls documentation.](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Server_Name)

The correct way to do this would be to write multiple server directives as shown by the documentation:

```
server {
  server_name www.domain.com;
  return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  server_name domain.com;
  [...]
}
```

The reason this is more 'correct' is described at the page linked:

> There are actually three problems here. The first being if directives.
>   That's what we care about now. Why is this bad? Did you read [If is
>   Evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)? With if directives Nginx is forced to evaluate every request for
>   all domains. Evaluating every request against if directives is
>   extremely inefficient. Avoid using if directives and use two server
>   directives as shown.

Answer (score -4):

Try that :

Apache :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourDomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourDomain.fr/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Nginx :

```
# nginx configuration

location / {
  if ($http_host ~* "^www\.yourDomain\.com$"){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://yourDomain.fr/$1 redirect;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's still apache isn't it?

Comment: Removed the -1 which was perfectly justified when your answer was just a block of apache configuration which didn't answer the question.

Comment: Just miss to copie de second part of the answer. Nobody is perfect.. The nginx code work ?

Comment: __"This is a wrong, cumbersome, and ineffective way."__ © [nginx.org](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html)